# Can't exit out of afiedt.buf

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, vi

This is a very simple question that I can't find the answer to. I am in sqlplus (Oracle) and I made a typo and typed "edit" which opens up "afiedt.buf" which I understand will open my default editor which is "vi". Once I am in the editor I get "Wrote file afiedt.buf". Then I would like to see what the contents of the file is. When I type anything, I get a "?". Once I get the "?" I can not ctrl c, ctrl z or anything to get out. How can I exit out and see the contents of the file. I also tried "wq" and "!q". Neither of these commands worked. I would like to be able to edit the file once I have made an error and not type it over. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you end up in the ED editor, which you don't know how to use. I had the same problem ... An elegant solution is to manipulate `GLOGIN.SQL` to set your preferred editor. This even shows changing `_EDITOR` as well : http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/login.html . Alternatively, use `! vi yourfile` (in Unix/Linux) to edit files from SQLPLUS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure `vi` as SQLPlus editor with the statement `DEFINE _EDITOR=vi` (see the [SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm#r4c1-t30)).

If you get back just a `?` you are probably using the old `ed` editor which you can quit by entering the `q` command (see its guide with `man ed`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Defining the editor will make life simpler.

Answer (score 1):

To come out of sqlplus when any text editor 'vi' or `notepad` is not configured is by pressing `Shift + q` and Enter, you will be back into `SQL> prompt`.

Once you have come out of blank/stuck session back to SQL prompt, you can follow above mentioned suggestions to define an editor.

Try and enjoy!